# How to output the MySQL EXPLAIN data in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if there is a way to output the EXPLAIN data from an MYSQL statement to PHP.

For studying I need to write a small application in PHP that outputs data via a SELECT query from a MYSQL DB. I have to output the EXPLAIN data, like searched rows etc.,  from this query as well. If I just set EXPLAIN in front of the SELECT, I get an Error.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a satisfying answer on the internet.

Due to I'm new to PHP, I would appreciate if someone can give me an example or smth like this.

Thank you guys!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to grab it using standard array tools. By using `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);` we can just grab the first return without a column name

```
$sql = 'EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = "condition"';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```